# Unicode drawText "Right to Left" Language issue in GraphicsMagick for node

Tags: graphicsmagick

Im using [GraphicsMagick for node](https://github.com/aheckmann/gm) and trying to drawText on image for "Urdu/Arabic Language" this text "السلام عليكم", text is being drawn on output image but it is being drawn "Left to Right" while it must be "Right to Left" as Arabic/Urdu are "Right to Left" languages.

```
gm("/file.png")
             .fill('#FF0066')
             .drawText(100, -150, "السلام عليكم", 'Center')
             .font("/alvi_Nastaleeq.ttf")
             .fontSize('38px')
             .encoding('Unicode')
```

Output Image:

[image]

If Im trying using reverse urdu "مكيلع مالسلا" string even then text isn't being drawn correctly.

[image]

What m i doing wrong? How can I fix it?

Thanks,

Comment: Have you tried reversing the text?
`drawText(100, -150, "مكيلع مالسلا", 'Center')`

Comment: it seems characters are being printed individually in both cases, I have updated question, any other suggestion?

Comment: did you solve the problem? @AqibMumtaz

Comment: This is bit old question, I was not able to solve it that time, plz post answer if you would be abel to..

Answer (score 4):

i'm searching for the same thing and i found that 
you need to enable the **text_shaping** option 
you need to configure FFmpeg with **--enable-libfribidi**

read about text_shaping here
https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#Syntax
i didn't test it but i will,
when i get a result i will post the code here
i wish i have pointed you out
here's a working code i use to produce videos like this
[image]

```
ffmpeg -y -loop 1 -framerate 25 -i bachground-img.jpg -vf "drawtext=text_shaping=1:fontfile=C\/:/Windows/Fonts/tradbdo.ttf:\
textfile=text-new.txt:fontcolor=white:fontsize=75:x=(w-tw)/2:y=h-25*t:" -t 45 -pix_fmt yuv420p output.mp4
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. this is bit old question. it would be great if you could post a working code

Comment: I'm using complied windows version and it's not support `libfribidi` do I have to recompile it on windows from source !

Answer (score 0):

I face exactly the same problem, and after days of searching I found a great npm library which fix this problem, the good thing with this library is that it works with both English & Arabic languages.

the library is : **@mapbox/mapbox-gl-rtl-text**.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/@mapbox/mapbox-gl-rtl-text

```
const rtlText = require('@mapbox/mapbox-gl-rtl-text');

var arabicString = "السلام عليكم";
var shapedArabicText = rtlText.applyArabicShaping(arabicString);
var readyForDisplay = rtlText.processBidirectionalText(shapedArabicText, []);
```